# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (16, 1, 2) but got array with shape (2, 1, 1)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm very new to using machine learning and keras. This is my first CNN model. I built a model to classify the sounds into the UrbanSound8kDataset. When I run the model on a small dummy set, I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (16, 1, 2) but got array with shape (2, 1, 1)
```

I looked at other posts with similar issues and tried changing the model loss to sparse_categorical_crossentropy rather than categorical_crossentropy. I also added model.flatten() before the first dense layer. Unfortunately, none of that resolved my error.

Here is the relevant code for my model:

```
num_labels = yy.shape[1]
filter_size = 2
num_rows = 1
num_columns = 1
num_channels = 1    

x_train = x_train.reshape(x_train.shape[0], num_rows, num_columns, num_channels)
y_train = y_train.reshape(y_train.shape[0], 2, num_columns, num_channels)
x_test = x_test.reshape(x_test.shape[0], 1, num_columns, num_channels)
y_test = y_test.reshape(y_test.shape[0], 2, num_columns, num_channels)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(num_rows,

    num_columns, num_channels), activation='relu', data_format='channels_first',   padding="same"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

#Flatten layer here:

model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')

model.summary()


num_epochs = 100
num_batch_size = 132

start = datetime.now()



model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=num_batch_size, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=1)
```

Here is the model summary:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 1, 1)          80        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 1, 1)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 16, 1, 1)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 1, 32)         64        
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 1, 32)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 16, 1, 32)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 1, 64)         2112      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 1, 64)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)          (None, 16, 1, 64)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 16, 1, 64)         4160      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 16, 1, 64)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_4 (Dropout)          (None, 16, 1, 64)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 16, 1, 2)          130       
=================================================================
Total params: 6,546
Trainable params: 6,546
Non-trainable params: 0
____________________________
```

The error occurs in the last line of the code I concluded, the model.fit line.

Please let me know if I need to include more code. This is only my second time posting here, so I was not sure how much code to include.

Thank you very much!

Comment: how many classes are there in data.?

Comment: There are ten classes: air_conditioner, car_horn, children_playing, dog_bark, drilling, enginge_idling, gun_shot, jackhammer, siren, and street_music.

Comment: is your label one hot encoded.?,for multiclass classification keras require one hot encoded labels..last dense layer with softmax activation should always have number of classes as input, like this `model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))`..you have done many things wrong

Comment: Thank you for letting me know that! I hadn't known about that requirement, but I will definitely try it. I want to point out, though, that I had used that syntax in the Dense layer (I just used num_labels, which had value 10, to make my code a bit more readable.) This was the Dense line: model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax')). Would you mind pointing out the other mistakes you see in my code so that I can resolve them?

Comment: your model summary says it all... There is no way you should get same output shape every time as your first element is 16 everytime.....you have started building your model with wrong parameters...to begin with your input shape parameter is wrong why is it 1.?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I fixed the issue. How do I close this thread?

Comment: just answer your question about how you solved it..like how others would answer.